# Gradle Local Module Transitive Dependency

Tags: java, spring, gradle, build.gradle

My project structure is -

```
ParentDirectory\
    GradleProjectA\
        build.gradle
    GradleProjectB\
        build.gradle
```

added `Spring` dependency in `GradleProjectA`,

now -
How can I add the `GradleProjectA` in `GradleProjectB`, so that same Spring dependency will be added/transited to `GradleProjectB`?
So that I need not to add Spring dependency again in `GradleProjectB`.

If I make a JAR of `GradleProjectA` and add the JAR to `GradleProjectB`, then `Spring` dependency is **not** transited to `GradleProjectB`

Answer (score 0):

please see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies_between_subprojects.html

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':shared')
}
```